# Test passing on TestFX, but not in headless mode

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, testfx

I am using TestFX to test selecting multiple items in a `ListView` using the `Ctrl` key, then clicking a button, which generates an alert dialog whose content is based on the items selected.

```
press(KeyCode.CONTROL);
clickOn((Node) lookup(hasText("Item 0")).query());
verifyThat((Node) lookup(hasText("Item 0")).query(), Node::isFocused);
clickOn((Node) lookup(hasText("Item 1")).query());
verifyThat((Node) lookup(hasText("Item 1")).query(), Node::isFocused);
clickOn((Node) lookup(hasText("Item 2")).query());
verifyThat((Node) lookup(hasText("Item 2")).query(), Node::isFocused);
release(KeyCode.CONTROL);

clickOn("actionButton");
alertDialogHasHeaderAndContent("Items selected: 3"); // my own function
```

**In headful mode**

The tests all pass.

**In headless mode**

The three `verifyThat` tests all pass, but when it clicks on the button and verifies that the resulting alert dialog is correct, it isn't; the alert generated is as if only one item from the list was selected.

It results in:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Items selected: 3
Actual   :Items selected: 1
```

---

Here is `alertDialogHasHeaderAndContent` for completeness:

```
/**
 * Checks the current alert dialog displayed (on the top of the window stack) has the expected contents.
 *
 * From https://stackoverflow.com/a/48654878/8355496
 * Licenced under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
 * @param expectedHeader Expected header of the dialog
 * @param expectedContent Expected content of the dialog
 */
private void alertDialogHasHeaderAndContent(final String expectedHeader, final String expectedContent) {
    final Stage actualAlertDialog = getTopModalStage();
    assertNotNull(actualAlertDialog);

    final DialogPane dialogPane = (DialogPane) actualAlertDialog.getScene().getRoot();
    assertEquals(expectedHeader, dialogPane.getHeaderText());
    assertEquals(expectedContent, dialogPane.getContentText());
}

/**
 * Get the top modal window.
 *
 * Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48654878/8355496
 * Licenced under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
 * @return the top modal window
 */
private Stage getTopModalStage() {
    // Get a list of windows but ordered from top[0] to bottom[n] ones.
    // It is needed to get the first found modal window.
    final List<Window> allWindows = new ArrayList<>(new FxRobot().robotContext().getWindowFinder().listWindows());
    Collections.reverse(allWindows);

    return (Stage) allWindows
            .stream()
            .filter(window -> window instanceof Stage)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: I have posted this as an issue on TestFX's Github page and got a response: https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/issues/566

Comment: Which OS are you testing in?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint

Comment: The reason of my asking this question is I had a similar problem. I am using Mac OS X, and instead of `press(KeyCode.COMMAND);` I was using `press(KeyCode.CONTROL);` and my test failed because multiple selection is allowed by pressing Command button on Mac OS by Control button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with Monocole. See https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/issues/566 for more information.